# My AJAX script is not giving any output

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

index.php:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="food.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 </head>    
 <body onloadd="process()">
 <div class="container">
 <h2 class="page-header">The Chuff Bucket</h2>

 <strong>Enter the food you want to order:</strong><br><br>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userInput">

<div id="underInput">

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

foodstore.php

```
    <?php
    header('Content-Type:text/xml');
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>';

    echo '<response>';

    $food = $_GET['food'];
    $foodArray = array('tuna','bacon','loaf','sandwich','pizza');
    if(in_array($food, $foodArray))
    {
        echo 'We do have'.$food.'!';
    }
    elseif($food=='')
    {
        echo 'Enter a food chomu';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'We have no'.$food;
    }

  echo '</response>';
  ?>
```

food.js"-

```
   var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

  function createXmlHttpRequestObject()
  {
    var xmlHttp;

    if(window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        try{

            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        try{

            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        }
        catch(e)
        {
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }
    if(!xmlHttp)
    {
        alert("Cannot create the object!!");
    }
    else
    {
        return xmlHttp;
    }
    }

    function process() {

    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 0 || xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
    {
    var food =   encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("userInput").value);
    xmlHttp.open("GET","foodstore.php?food="+food,true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse();
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
    else
    {
      setTimeout('process()',1000);
    }
    }

    function handleServerResponse() {
      if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
      {
        if (xmlHttp.Status == 200)
        {
            xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
            xmlDocElm = xmlResponse.documentElement;
            msg = xmlDocElm.firstChild.data;
            document.getElementById("underInput").innerHtml = '<span style="color:blue;">'+msg+'</span>';
            setTimeout('process()',1000);

        }
        else
        {
            alert("Something is wrong!!");
        }
        }
        }
```

I just started with AJAX and this is my first code. I have even free hosted it. Here is the url:- [Chuff Bucket](http://mutoashirogi.16mb.com/)
I have no idea what is wrong with the code. I have done the same as shown in the tutorial.

Comment: I would recommend using [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). jQuery is a javascript framework. It permit many thing, including simplified AJAX requests.

Comment: Ok I'll try that but what is wrong with this type of AJAX?

Comment: Basically, nothing is wrong. This is how AJAX was used 10 years ago. Now, it has been simplified with libraries like jQuery and Mootools, so simplify your life and use the easy way =)

Comment: I just added an example of what you are trying to do but with a jQuery version. Just dont forget to DL jQuery and add it to your page has a javascript ressource =)

Comment: @ThinkTank Thanks a lot

Comment: @ThinkTank that is the WRONG response. you should never recommend someone to use jquery before they understand how it works in javascript.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't doing what you think:

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse();
```

This is invoking the `handleServerResponse` function *immediately* (which doesn't do anything, because `xmlHttp.readyState` isn't `4` at that time), and setting the *result* of that function to the `onreadystatechange` callback.  Since that function doesn't return anything, that result is `undefined`.

Don't invoke the function, just set it like a variable as the callback:

```
mlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
```

Comment: I got an alert which I wrote in the javascript file saying "Something is wrong!"

Comment: @AshirogiMuto: Presumably that would mean that `xmlHttp.Status` isn't `200` when that code executes.  You may want to examine the response from the server to see what the problem might be.

Comment: Thanks I'll see the server file

Comment: @AshirogiMuto: Then it sounds like you're going to have to do some debugging.  If the response code from the server is something other than `200` then you'll have to start by examining that response.

Answer (score -1):

There is javascript framework offering a simplified way to use Ajax request like [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).
Using this kind of framework is a good way to simplify your code and to not repeat yourself [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

A jQuery version :

```
<script>
$(document).on('keyup', '#userInput', function(){
    var food = $(this).val(); // # <= means ID
    $.get('foodstore.php', 'food='+food, function(response){
        $('#underInput').html(response);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'll surely try jquery ajax

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. [jQuery AJAX Basics](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I mention why he should try this directly in the question's comments. But you are true. Better twice than once.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thanks for the tutorial link

Comment: I changed my asnwer : I have added a listener. This way, when user 'll type something in your input, it'll send a request to check the answer.